# R Sweave: Create tabularx from tabular; How to use print?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

[SOLVED]

Purpose is to generate from a tabular table a tabularx table. But I do not now how I can use print for this purpose, because print prints the table to PDF file before creating tabularx.

Code:

```
t <- read.csv("CSV-Path", header = T, na.strings = c(""), sep = ",")
xT <- xtable(t)
xTx <- strsplit(print(xT, size="\\tiny", caption.placement = "top", include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE), "\n")
xTx <- unlist(xTx)
xTx[4] <- gsub("l", "X", xTx[4])
xTx[4] <- gsub("tabuXar", "tabularx", xTx[4])
xTx[14] <- gsub("tabular", "tabularx", xTx[14])
```

The problem is that the table is printed at line 3. But I need to use print for generating the real tabular table so that the tabularx can be created.

Comment: Using results:hide in beginning: << tRR , echo=FALSE, results=hide>>= and opening a new R-Code-Block solves the first problem with print().

Comment: But now the row names are printted using print: [1], [2], [3], ....

Comment: Saving Variable xTx as. txt.-file and loading with LaTeX solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving Variable xTx as txt.-file and loading with LaTeX solves the problem.